# Something Wrong with router.all() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on node.js web app where I am using express-router to
route  requests. Now, i have two views- one is Home and other is Admin
and their respective  routes are set as -:

```
router.all('/*', (req, res, next)=>{   //For admin
    req.app.locals.layout='admin';
    next();
});

router.all('/*', (req, res, next)=>{    //For Home
    req.app.locals.layout='home';
    next();
});
```

and both are configured as -:

```
app.use('/',home);          // in app.js viz the >entry point
app.use('/admin',admin);    //
```

Problem- the Home view works fine and Admin view has further routes as -:

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('admin/index');
});
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('admin/dashboard');
});
```

My problem is that when i open localhost:4000/admin/, It opens fine as 
expected BUT when i open localhost:4000/admin/dashboard it
again shows page  which was set for localhost:4000/admin/...what can
be the problem ??

[image: This is the localhost:4000/admin working as expected]

[image: This is the localhost:4000/dashboard which again shows same home page without css]

Comment: Do you mean that the CSS for the dashboard seems to be missing? This is typically caused by not using absolute paths to resources (like CSS files).

Comment: No that should not have happened instead, i wanted to display the content which was meant for /dashboard route but it is not rendering that required content,,what can be the problem?? like when it would /dashboard route, <h2>Dashboard</h2> should have been rendered but it is displaying this homepage-without-CSS

Comment: I just realized that the real problem is that res.send('hello') is working fine with a Route but res.render() is not working fine so not displaying the page i want for given Route...Please help me !